# detach .exe from perl main script

Tags: perl

I am stuck here..:( I am trying to execute an temp.exe file from Perl script.

I tried using the following:

1)

```
         $pid=  open( CMD, "| exp.exe  > C:\exp_out.txt" );
         print CMD "arg1\n";
         print CMD "arg2\n";
         print CMD "arg3\n";
```

Now this exp.exe keeps running in the background without any problem. but if I want to close it and start it again it starts the exp.exe but does not provide input arguments to the exp.exe

Closing:

```
         system("taskkill /F /T /pid $pid");`
```

Now this is a part of 2 sub routines open and close...

I also tried Open2;Win32::Process;
Open2 is stuck at exp.exe and Win32::Process I dont know how to pass multiple arguments.

Comment: Your formatting makes it seem like your perl script actually calls each line in tick marks. Is that the way you're running it, or is it bad formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing arguments in the command line. Printing to the CMD is like typing text after you open the pipe. If this IS what you want, then your program `exp.exe` needs to expect input from STDIN

```
$pid = open(CMD, "| exp.exe arg1 arg2 arg3 > file.txt");
#do your work here
close(CMD)
```